# Failure to connect an Azure Web App (Go app) to Azure Flexible Database for MySQL

Tags: azure, go, azure-web-app-service, azure-database-mysql

I have a basic Go API I created that works and connects locally. However, when I try to connect it from an Azure Web App I get the error "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process."

I am using Gorm

```
    import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1"
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    )
    var DB *gorm.DB
```

**The database connection code is as follows:**

````
    DbDriver := os.Getenv("DB_DRIVER")
    DbPort := os.Getenv("DB_PORT")
    DbHost := os.Getenv("DB_HOST")
    DbUser := os.Getenv("DB_USER")
    DbPassword := os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD")
    DbName := os.Getenv("DB_NAME")

    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local", DbUser, DbPassword, DbHost, DbPort, DbName)

    DB, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})```

Tried even connecting to an AWS database and encountered the same error. What could be missing on this?
````

Answer (score 0):

Check the below workaround to Connect to MySQL database via Gorm

Create `main.go` file and add the below code:

```cs
package main
import (
 "encoding/json"
 "fmt"
 "log"
 "net/http"
 "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
 "gorm.io/gorm"
)
// Database Connection
var  dsn =
", GoDatabaseCreate) log.Fatal"siliconuser:UserName@Password@tcp(siliconmysql.mysql.database.azure.com:3306)/go_test_models?charset=utf8mb4"
var  db, _ = gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

type  GoTestModel  struct {
Name string
Year string
}
func  main() {
 http.HandleFunc("/createstuff (http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
func  GoDatabaseCreate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
GoTestModel := GoTestModel{
Name: "john",
Year: "2022"}
 db.Create(&GoTestModel)
 if  err := db.Create(&GoTestModel).Error; err != nil {
 log.Fatalln(err)
    }
 json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(GoTestModel)
 fmt.Println("Feilds Added", GoTestModel)
}
```

In Azure portal, run the below commands in Azure cloud shell (Bash)

```cs
$ mysql -h siliconmysql.mysql.database.azure.com -u siliconuser -p

Enter password: Your Pwd

create database go_test_models;
use go_test_models
create table go_test_models(Name VARCHAR(100), Year VARCHAR(100));
```

Run code in VS code and connect to database in Azure

Right click on the `main.go` file and select `Open in Integrated Terminal`. Run `go mod init gotest` command to install and initialize all the modules.

[image]

- `go.mod`  file will be added.
  [image]
- To get our modules, run `go get gorm.io/driver/mysql` command
  [image]
- Run `go get gorm.io/gorm` command
- Run our code locally by using  `Run- go run main.go` command.
- Deploy app to our Azure app service.
  [image]

[image]

> "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process."

Configure Custom Auto heal to know the more details about the issue

In `Azure Portal` => Navigate to your `Azure App Service` => `Diagnose and solve problems` => Select `Diagnostic Tools` => `Auto Heal` => `Custom Auto-Heal Rules`
[image]

[image]

References taken from [GORM](https://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll give this a test drive and feedback.